# Vue: How to redirect Page for each session

Tags: redirect, vue.js

I am using vuejs frontend and backend nodejs.

I need to do the following:

URL `paster/user/A` redirects to `paster/session/ghb72fvd` (where wait 5 seconds is displayed) -> redirects to `paster/session/cas390yd` (where wait 5 seconds is displayed) -> `paster/user/book5`

I am thinking of having anything with paster/session/* redirects to a single page so that I need to create only one page in vue.

```
paster/session/ghb72fvd -> goes to page A
paster/session/cas390yd -> goes to the same page A
```

Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

**Updated:**

```
vuejs


export default {

redirectTimeout(() => this.$router.push({path: redirectSession }), 5000)

methods: {
    getRedirectSession(redirectSession){
        calls processSessionUrl() from nodejs
    }
}
```

In Nodejs:has an array of `[ghb72fvd, cas390yd]`

```
If redirectSession is null choose first item in array. If redirectSession == ghb72fvd return second item
}
```

Comment: Sure, you can definitely do this. What have you tried?

Comment: This almost definitely isn't the correct way to manage sessions, you should probably be handling this with a cookie. From there you could create an 'authenticated' endpoint and do whatever you need to do with the session from there. Note that an authenticated route like this would need to be handled by a webserver like express or with vue-router.

Comment: Updated @Ohgodwhy.

Comment: @harryparkdotio do you mean I need to store all the sessions in a cookie?

Comment: Session tokens at least